# Blindar parámetros PDO desde función

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

estoy trabajando con PDO en PHP. Tengo la siguiente función:

```
function SQL($Pcon){
  require("pdo.php");
  $Vr= $VGcon->prepare($Pcon);
  $result = $Vr->execute();
  $VGcon = null;
  if($result){
       return $Vr->fetchAll(); 
  }
  return "Ocurrió un error";
```

La uso de la siguiente manera:

```
    $username='usu1';
    $password='123';
    SQL("INSERT INTO usuarios (username, password) VALUES ($username, $password)");
```

Todo eso me funciona bien, el problema es que como ven en la función no se blindan los parametros. Entonces lo que quisiera es desde la función SQL analizar la consulta, extraer los parámetros y blindarlos.

Answer (score 1):

Tu consulta puede seguir la siguiente estructura

```
$username;
$password;
$insert = "INSERT INTO usuarios (username, password) VALUES (:username, :password)";
$procesainsert = $conexion->prepare($insert);
$procesainsert->bindParam(':username', $username);
$procesainsert->bindParam(':password', $password);
$procesainsert->execute();
```

**EXPLICACIÓN**

1. Primero dentro del insert en lugar de pasar de manera directa las variables, les colocamos un alias; para el ejemplo yo puse unos que tuvieran los mismo nombres checa que cada alias lleva justo antes el signo de 2puntos.
2. Posterior con una nueva variable accedo a la conexion y despues al método prepare para **preparar dicha consulta**
3. En esta ocasión como inserto 2 valores hago un bindParam para cada valor por separado, recibo 2 valores; el primero es el alias que coloque en el insert entre comillas y separado por una coma ahora si paso el nombre de la variable que esta mandando el usuario
4. Finalmente hago que la variable que contiene la query acceda al métod execute() para que se procese dicha inserción

> ¿Por qué colocar alias a mi consulta?, evitar la inyección SQL ya que
>   así no suministras los valores que manda el usuario de manera directa
>   si no hasta después de que son tratados.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, ya se hacerlo de esta manera, lo que quisiera es algo como lo siguiente: